# Registering on PyPI test site command line ValueError

Tags: git, github, pypi

Why is the below happening when I try to register my package with the test site? It registers with the regular site just fine :/

This is what happens at my command line when I attempt to register with the pypi test site:

```
PS C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2Distribution> python setup.py register -r https://testpypi.python.org
i
running register
running egg_info
writing hellodmt2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to hellodmt2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to hellodmt2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'hellodmt2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'hellodmt2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    download_url = "https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2/archive/0.1.tar.gz",
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\register.py", line 10, in run
    orig.register.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\register.py", line 46, in run
    self._set_config()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\register.py", line 81, in _set_config
    raise ValueError('%s not found in .pypirc' % self.repository)
ValueError: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi not found in .pypirc
PS C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2Distribution>
```

My setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except importError:
    from distutils.core import setup

setup(name = "hellodmt2",
      description = "a source distribution test",
      version = "0.1",
      author = "David",
      author_email = "dmt257257@gmail.com",
      py_modules = ["hellodmt2"],
      url = "https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2",
      download_url = "https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2/archive/0.1.zip",
      keywords = ["testing"],

      )
```

This is my pypirc:

```
    [distutils]
index-servers=
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository = https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username = dmt257
password = mypasswordhere

[pypi]
repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username = dmt257
password = mypasswordhere
```

Comment: The file should be `.pypirc` (note the leading `.`) or is that just a typo? Where have you located this file?

Comment: The file is 'pypi.pypirc'. I've pointed to it's location in system variables -> Path. I think I need to make a HOME env var and point to it's location in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file should be called, simply, `.pypirc`, not `pypi.pypirc`. This a Linux-style filename commonly used for configuration files. The leading dot means that it won't be shown in a normal directory listing.

And from what I have read, the Windows equivalent of the Linux `$Home` directory (`~`) is `C\Users\<logged-in-user>`, so `C\Users\Dave`, in your case. Adding the location to your `PATH` won't help; this variable is only to allow Windows to find executables.

The documentation isn't clear on where this file should go in a Windows environment, there is an old [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1741) that mentions this file not being found in Windows because of the lack of a `HOME` envorinment variable. It's been 'fixed' but it's still not clear where the file should go, other than `~/.pypirc`.

I'd try renaming your file, first. If you still have issues, try moving it to your 'home' directory. Note that the Windows GUI won't let you rename a file with only an extension, so you'll have to do it from a command window:

`rename pypi.pypirc .pypirc`

Comment: Mucho appreciated SiHa. Simply changing to .pypypird didn't work but neither did creating a HOME environ var and pointing it to the location of .pypirc. I tried both, but should HOME go in System or User variables?

Comment: I don't think the solution is creating a HOME variable, rather placing the file in your home directory (Which is `C:\Users\Dave`, looking at your output, above)

Comment: Ahha! The first thing I noticed was that there was already a .pypirc file in there. I assume it was created when I was prompted at the command line to save my username/pw during registration to the main site(I did this before using the test). Replaced it with mine above and it now works! Thank you very much. I'm actaully getting some wins today ha.

Comment: Nice - glad I could help.